# Swift - Issue with variable scope with parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm struggling with a problem since 2 days with Swift calling a parse.com class.

1. I have a variable declared at the root of the UIViewController class

   var myVariable: String?
2. I created a function to call the database and return a value

   func retrieveData() {

   ```
       // Create the query
       var queryTest:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "myClasseName")

       // Where clause
       queryTest.whereKey("columnName", equalTo: "someText")

       queryTest.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (myParseObject:PFObject!, errreur: NSError!) -> Void in

           self.myVariable = myParseObject["nameOfColumnOfContainerTheValueToBeReturned"] as? String

           println("valeurTest dans la BD = \(self.myVariable)")
       }

   }
   ```

So far the println inside the function returns my value! Great

The problem starts when I call my function inside viewDidLoad. I want to change the value of myVariable by calling the retrieveData() function. However, the variable value does not change!

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.retrieveData()

            // The myVariable value should change

            println("My new value =\(self.myVariable)")

        }
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` is asynchronous (i.e. it executes on a background thread) so you have to wait for it to complete before accessing the value. By attempting to print immediately after calling `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock`'s method, you're attempting to print a variable that hasn't been retrieved yet since `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` hasn't had enough time to fetch the data.

In your first block of code, `self.myVariable` is able to print successfully since it's executed within the block and thus *after* the fetch has completed.

Comment: Thanks Lindsey. I added the following at the end of the function. Again, the println is OK inside the function and I still get the initial value after calling the function inside viewDidLoad and tracing the result with println dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.myVariable = myParseObject["nameOfColumnOfContainerTheValueToBeReturned"] as String
                println("Asynch = \(self.myVariable)")
                
            })

Comment: @FrancisBeaulieu Yes, my answer explains why the println is OK within but can't print in your viewDidLoad... I don't know how much clearer I can be... You can't do a println outside of the block immediately after executing the block because the variable won't be ready yet. The block's still at work in the background during that println in your viewDidLoad. It needs more time.